# How can I tap into a UIView's changing values during an animateWithDuration block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uislider

I am using animateWithDuration to change the value of a UISlider:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{ [myUISlider setValue:10]; }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
```

The problem is, I need to be able to display the current value of the UISlider *while it is changing*.  Is this even possible using animateWithDuration?  I tried creating a UISlider subclass and overriding setValue in hopes of getting access to the slider's value as it is being changed:

```
-(void)setValue:(float)newValue
{
    [super setValue:newValue];

    NSLog(@"The new value is: %f",newValue);
}
```

But that code only gets called at the very *end* of the animation block.  In a way that makes perfect sense, since I really only called setValue once.  But I was hoping that the animation block would somehow call it over and over again within its internal mechanisms, but that appears not to be the case.

If UIView animateWithDuration is a dead-end here, I wonder if there is a better way to acheive this same functionality with something else?  Perhaps another slick little block-driven part of the SDK I don't know about which allows animating more than just UIView parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to handle it is to code a custom `Slide` you can creat it like progress bar which there are many demo on github.

You can also use `NSTimer` to do it , but I do not think it is a very better way.

When you tap , you can creat a `timer` :

`_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(setValueAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

and set a ivar: `_value = oldValue;`

in the `setValueAnimation` method :

```
- (void)setValueAnimation
{
    if (_value >= newValue) {
        [_timer invalidate];
        _value = newValue;
        [self setVale:_value];
        return;
    }

    _value += .05;

    [self setVale:_value];

}
```

**UPDATE**

how to add block:

1st:you can define a block handler :

```
typedef void (^CompleteHandler)();
```

2nd: creat your block and added it into the userInfo :

```
CompleteHandler block = ^(){
    NSLog(@"Complete");
};

NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:block,@"block", nil];
```

3rd: make the `NSTimer`:

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(setValueAnimation:) userInfo:userInfo repeats:YES];
```

4th:achieve your timer method:

```
- (void)setValueAnimation:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if (_value >= newValue) {
        [_timer invalidate];
        _value = newValue;
        [self setVale:_value];

        // also can use [_delegate complete];

        CompleteHandler block = [timer.userInfo objectForKey:@"block"];
        if (block) {

              block();

        }
        return;
    }

    _value += .05;

    [self setVale:_value];

}
```

Comment: Right, it would just be nice to be able to use apple's ease in easeout parameters and block structure.. maybe it's not possible.

Comment: @todd412 of course you can use block and custom "easein" "easeout". You can creat a block handler as a ivar , and add it in the userInfo.  you can invocate the block or callback delegate before the "return" to tell you the setValueAnimation is finish. And you can custom the time fuction by yourself to achieve the "easein" "easeout" it just dynamic set the "_value += dynamicValue"

Comment: @todd412 if you do what I tell above ,why not creat a custom `Silder` ?

Comment: that sounds interesting, can you edit your post with some sample code to show what you're describing about creating the block with userinfo?

Comment: @todd412 see my update , maybe you should deal with the exception by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is any sort of notification that you could "tap into" to get the UIView animation "steps", but you can do the animations "manually" using an NSTimer, and that will allow you to continuously update your value.

Comment: Right, that probably is a good alternative, although it loses the convenience of the built-in EaseIn and EaseOut parameters and the block structure..

Answer (score 0):

If there's an out of the box solution using UIView - I'm all ears. This animation framework (only 2 classes!) - PRTween https://github.com/chris838/PRTween will give you access to convenience timing functions and also the changed value.

Here's an updated project of mine https://github.com/jdp-global/KACircleProgressView/

```
PRTweenPeriod *period = [PRTweenPeriod periodWithStartValue:0 endValue:10.0 duration:1.0];

PRTweenOperation *operation = [PRTweenOperation new];
operation.period = period;
operation.target = self;
operation.timingFunction = &PRTweenTimingFunctionLinear;
operation.updateSelector = @selector(update:)

[[PRTween sharedInstance] addTweenOperation:operation]

- (void)update:(PRTweenPeriod*)period {
  [myUISlider setValue:period.tweenedValue];
}
```